# Uncaught Type Error :Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load examples my instructor posted on his webpage to make sure my laptop can work with WebGL. I opened his examples beforehand and they worked, simply displaying a square in a square. So I went and copied and pasted the exact codes he had onto a notepad text editor, saved them as .js files, then did the same for the .html file and got the error as said in the title above. As I opened "Inspect Element", the part in particular with the error was:

```
var setupWebGL = function(canvas, opt_attribs) {
  function showLink(str) {
  var container = canvas.parentNode;
```

//Uncaught Type Error :Cannot Readproperty 'parentNode' of null

```
  if (container) {
    container.innerHTML = makeFailHTML(str);
    }
  };

  if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext) {
    showLink(GET_A_WEBGL_BROWSER);
    return null;
  }

  var context = create3DContext(canvas, opt_attribs);
  if (!context) {
    showLink(OTHER_PROBLEM);
  }
  return context;
};
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error? Since this code worked on the instructor's website, there has to be something I am missing. If you need more information/details on the question please let me know. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute vec4 vPosition;
void main()
{
  g1_Position = vPosition;
}
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type= "x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
void main()
{
   g1_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="square.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="g1-canvas" width="512" height="512">
Oops...your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show your html on jsfiddle.?

Answer (score 0):

The `showLink` function gets created in `setupWebGL` scope, and the problem is when the `showLink` gets invoked, `canvas` variable looses its value. to fix it you can do:

```
var setupWebGL = function (canvas, opt_attribs) {
    function showLink(str) {
        var container = showLink._canvas.parentNode;
        if (container) {
            container.innerHTML = makeFailHTML(str);
        }
    }
    showLink._canvas = canvas;
};
```